Spreadsheet formula using two variable in two array
This is a follow-up to my previous post
Query using two variable in two array
However, as I test further, when the combination table only has one row.  The result was not as expected.
Original Data



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5




A
aawek
ert
gh
dsfg


B
asfdklj
vnv
ghc
dfgs


D
sadf
dsfg
sfdg
hgdfh


E
erty
dfsg
sdfg
gfhre


F
tyher
dsfg
sdfg
dfsg



Combination of Col1



1
2




A
B



Using the following function as suggested in previous post:
=let(Σ,filter(A13:B,A13:A<>""),Λ,A4:E8,    reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(Σ)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,filter(Λ,xmatch(choosecols(Λ,1),index(Σ,c))),wraprows(rept("*",5),columns(Λ),rept("*",5))))))

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cuNkoR4Rn7Lt0u-aCB4487JnucMKYgx0ETn6R_w7-ds/edit?usp=sharing
Expected Result



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5




A
aawek
ert
gh
dsfg


B
asfdklj
vnv
ghc
dfgs


*****
*****
*****
*****
*****



Actual Result



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5




A
aawek
ert
gh
dsfg


*****
*****
*****
*****
*****



I tried to alter every variable in the formula but in vain.

You can use:
=REDUCE(A3:E3,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A13:A)),LAMBDA(a,i,IFNA(VSTACK(a,
  FILTER(A4:E8,REGEXMATCH(A4:A8,"^("&JOIN("|",INDEX(A13:B,i))&")$")),
  "*****"),"*****")))



TOCOL(,1) is used to prevent stacking the result on an empty row. It's essentialy a 0x1 array i.e. an array with 0 height. For what a and i stand for, I recommend to give a look at the official documentation.

Thanks @z.. , as I refer to the documentation, a is the accumulator and i is the current value.  However, I can't understand how it works when a is referring to 'A3:E3', which a should be a value instead of a range from documentation.  Would you please give more details?  Thanks.

the accumulator doesn't necessarily have to be a single value, it can be anything. A3:E3 is the initial value to which the first filter is stacked onto. At each iteration (i.e. at each change of i) a gets higher because we keep stacking the result of the previous combination to it.
